# where is the missing column when Converting a matrix/array to a data table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I get a matrix/array from an output. My goal is to convert it to a data table and make it print friendly. However, one key column was gone when doing the conversion..

```
dput(tab)
structure(c("   1950", "   ", "    207 (10.6) ", "    288 (14.8) ", 
"   1455 (74.6) ", "   ", "     95 ( 4.9) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", 
"   1823 (93.5) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "     32 ( 1.6) ", "4721.83 (1322.96)", 
"    553", "    ", "     27 ( 4.9) ", "     99 (17.9) ", "    427 (77.2) ", 
"    ", "     68 (12.3) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "    455 (82.3) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "     30 ( 5.4) ", "4698.88 (1356.03)", "    813", 
"    ", "     96 (11.8) ", "     64 ( 7.9) ", "    653 (80.3) ", 
"    ", "      8 ( 1.0) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "    804 (98.9) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "      1 ( 0.1) ", "4957.45 (1259.53)", "   1243", 
"   ", "    166 (13.4) ", "    191 (15.4) ", "    886 (71.3) ", 
"   ", "    129 (10.4) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "   1098 (88.3) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "     16 ( 1.3) ", "4861.85 (1221.35)", "", 
"<0.001", "", "", "", "   NaN", "", "", "", "", "", "<0.001", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = c(12L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("n", "Race (%)", "   Black", "   Other race", 
"   White", "Ethnicity (%)", "   Hispanic", "   No info", "   Non-hispnaic", 
"   Refused", "   Unknown", "dx_age (mean (SD))"), `Stratified by site` = c("Phila", 
"colorado", "nation", "Dup", "p", "test")))
```

When I converted tab to tap, the Dimnames in tab was gone.

```
tap <- as.data.table(tab)
dput(tap)
structure(list(Phila = c("   1950", "   ", "    207 (10.6) ", 
"    288 (14.8) ", "   1455 (74.6) ", "   ", "     95 ( 4.9) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "   1823 (93.5) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "     32 ( 1.6) ", 
"4721.83 (1322.96)"), colorado = c("    553", "    ", "     27 ( 4.9) ", 
"     99 (17.9) ", "    427 (77.2) ", "    ", "     68 (12.3) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "    455 (82.3) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "     30 ( 5.4) ", 
"4698.88 (1356.03)"), nation = c("    813", "    ", "     96 (11.8) ", 
"     64 ( 7.9) ", "    653 (80.3) ", "    ", "      8 ( 1.0) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "    804 (98.9) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "      1 ( 0.1) ", 
"4957.45 (1259.53)"), Dup = c("   1243", "   ", "    166 (13.4) ", 
"    191 (15.4) ", "    886 (71.3) ", "   ", "    129 (10.4) ", 
"      0 ( 0.0) ", "   1098 (88.3) ", "      0 ( 0.0) ", "     16 ( 1.3) ", 
"4861.85 (1221.35)"), p = c("", "<0.001", "", "", "", "   NaN", 
"", "", "", "", "", "<0.001"), test = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002621ef0>)
```

Did I do something wrong? or is there a better way to do the conversion, if not, how can I add this information back? Thanks a lot!

p.s
I also try change rownames of tap from data.frame but print out show X, X.1...which is an unintended results.

Comment: Try `data.table::setDT(as.data.frame(tab))`, then look at `tab`. It's converted by reference an you'll see no output.

Comment: or `tibble::as_tibble(tab, rownames = "dimnames")`

Comment: Thanks for answering! my ultimate goal is to be able to print the data table in shinyapp. Using tibble does add rownames but when display in shiny app,  unintended row numbers X,X.1... show in the display.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @ponyhd. As my answer was not useful, I deleted it. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone's tips, seems like there are no simple solution for this. My work around is to save rownames as permanent column and use regular expression to remove those lines starting with X within the column. Hope this will help those who came across similar issue.